# Complex power series (or not quite so?)

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm stuck with this problem. Any hints are appreciated.
It just says 
$$
\mbox{"For what values of}\ z\ \mbox{is}\quad 
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\left(z \over 1+z\right)^{n}\quad \mbox{convergent ?}
$$

The thing is that it doesn't look like a power series, but I guess I should transform it into that form so I can get its radius of convergence... Is that correct ?.
How can I go with that ?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a power series, but it is a geometric series; we know that in general,

$$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} r^n$$ converges if and only if $|r| < 1$. So notice that your sum would fit this format with $$r = \frac z {1 + z}$$

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thanks a lot. 
So all I need now is to set the modulus of $\frac{z}{1+z} $ smaller than 1 and solve, right?